# AngularJs get employee from factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise, angularjs-http

I've got a `employeeController` and a `employeeFactory` in the `employeeFactory` I receive an `employee` like this:

```
function employeeFactory(authenticationFactory,requestFactory,GLOBALS) {
        var factory = {};
        var vm = this;
        vm.employee = {};

        factory.getEmployee = function(id) {
            data = {"api_token": authenticationFactory.getToken()};
            url = GLOBALS.url + 'show/employee/' + id;
            requestFactory.post(url, data)
                .then(function (response) {
                    return vm.employee = response.data.result.Employee;
                }, function () {
                    $window.location.assign('/');
                });
        }
        return factory;
    }
```

In my controller I'm trying to receive it like this:

```
console.log(employeeFactory.getEmployee($routeParams.id));
```

But the result is null?

When I `console.log` the response in my `requestFactory` I receive an `employee` object. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reason behind it is, you missed to return promise of `requestFactory.post` from  `factory.getEmployee` method

**Code**

```
factory.getEmployee = function(id) {
  data = {"api_token": authenticationFactory.getToken()};
  url = GLOBALS.url + 'show/employee/' + id;
  return requestFactory.post(url, data)
    .then(function (response) {
      return vm.employee = response.data.result.Employee;
  }, function () {
      $window.location.assign('/');
  });
}
```

But even though you do it, you will not able to get value `employee` object printed. It will print promise object return by `$http.post` method/ `$resource` method

For getting hold on that object you need to use `.then` function over that promise object. like below

```
employeeFactory.getEmployee($routeParams.id).then(function(employee){
   console.log('Employee', employee)
})
```

Comment: @jamie Glad to help you.. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

We can use deferred api in angularjs for better communication between caller and service.

```
factory.getEmployee = function(id) {
 var deferred = $q.defer();
  data = {"api_token": authenticationFactory.getToken()};
  url = GLOBALS.url + 'show/employee/' + id;
  return requestFactory.post(url, data)
    .then(function (response) {     
          deferred.resolve(response.data.result.Employee);
  }, function () {
      deferred.reject();
  });
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

On your controller:

```
employeeFactory.getEmployee($routeParams.id).then(function(employee){
   console.log('Employee', employee)
},function(){
 $window.location.assign('/');
})
```

By this approach we can notify caller with some messages if your response gets delayed.
For more info see this link.
[angular promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)