# AngularJs empty result

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise, angularjs-http

I've got 2 `factory` functions:

**Factories**

```
factory.getCurrEmployee = function()
{
    data = {"api_token": authenticationFactory.getToken()};
    url = GLOBALS.url + 'show/employee/' + $cookieStore.get('employeeid');
    return requestFactory.post(url, data)
        .then(function (response) {
            return response.data.result.Employee;
        }, function () {
            $window.location.assign('/');
        });
}

factory.isSuperadministrator = function() {
    factory.getCurrEmployee().then(function (employee) {
        if(employee.Role == 'Superadministrator')
        {
            return true; //console.log('Superadministrator')    <- that console.log is visible in my console
        }
        return false;
    });
}
return factory;
```

In my controller I would expect true or false (a user is a Superadministrator or not) but the result is nothing. If I console.log in my factory.isSuperadministrator the result is true.

**Controller**

```
console.log(employeeFactory.isSuperadministrator());
```

Why is this not working?

Comment: Its async. Your returning promises not a bool value.

Comment: @ste2425 those `Boolean` value's will never get returned untill, promise gets returned. because `boolean` has been return from callback function.

Comment: @PankajParkar Yes, but the fact the OP has no use of `.then` in his calling controller code but is returning the expected value in the service callback shows an underlying lack of knowledge on how promise chaining works. Which is why i said he's returning a promise not the value in his callback.

Comment: @ste2425 apology.. I misunderstood it. though cheers..I think, OP got what he wanted :-)

Answer (score 4):

Missed to return promise from `factory.getCurrEmployee` in `factory.isSuperadministrator` function. Also I did small refactoring which makes your code more smarter.

```
factory.isSuperadministrator = function() {
    return factory.getCurrEmployee().then(function (employee) {
        return employee.Role == 'Superadministrator';
    });
}
```

But above thing doesn't solve your problem, it will only `print` promise object in `console`. To solve your problem further you need to put `.then` function with callback over promise returned by `employeeFactory.isSuperadministrator()` like below

**Controller**

```
employeeFactory.isSuperadministrator().then(function(data){
   console.log(res);
});
```

Do follow same guidelines which are described here in [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36202497/2435473)

Comment: Would still need `.then` in calling controller code.

Comment: @ste2425 could you look at referenced answer

Comment: That wasn't in your answer when i commented.

Comment: @PankajParkar Thanks again. But now I've to do the if statement in every controller again and again right?

Comment: @jamie that is how you should deal with promise(asynchronous) code.. Its regular pattern you should follow. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
employeeFactory.isSuperadministrator().then(function(res){
console.log(res);
});
```